# Eclipse show warnings in my first android project

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I am using Eclipse indigo, android sdk 8 (android api 2.2). When i create a new android project using

Name:Bucky

Package: com.theboston.android.bucky

eclipse shows a yellow triangle on the Project. The yellow triangle eventually [becomes red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzqtB.jpg)

A simple java project ansuljava works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eclipse problem view to explore any issues with your projects.

Go to **Window->Show View->Other->Problems**

you can also use **Window->Show View->Markers**, but this one is more cluttered with less problematic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**Project > Clean > Clean Project**

This will force Eclipse to regenerate some of the code and rebuild everything. Wait a few seconds, then the red flag(s) should go away.